# Question in the proof of Lusin's theorem.

Tags: analysis, lebesgue-integral

I want to prove Lusin's theorem.

> Let $E\subset\mathbb R$ be a measurable set and $f:E\to\mathbb R$ be a measurable function. Then, for each $\epsilon$, there exists $F\subset E$ s.t. $F$ is closed about relative topology from $E$, $m^\ast(E\setminus F)<\epsilon$, $f|_F$ is continuous. ($m^\ast$ is Lebesgue outer measure.)

I've already understand the case $m^\ast(E)<\infty$, and I'm trying general case.

Hint is given : Consider $E_k:=E\cap[-k,k]$.

---

Let $E_k:=E\cap[-k,k]$.

For each $k\in\mathbb N$, $m^\ast(E_k)<\infty$ and $f|_{E_k}$ is measurable thus there is $F_k\subset E_k$ s.t. $F_k$ is closed about relative topology from $E_k$, $m^\ast(E_k\setminus F_k)<\epsilon/2^k$, $f|_{F_k}$ is continuous.

$F:=\cup_{k=1}^\infty F_k$, $E:=\cup_{k=1}^\infty E_k$.

Then $F\subset E$.

Since $E\setminus F\subset\cup_{k=1}^\infty (E_k\setminus F_k)$, I get $m^\ast(E\setminus F)\leqq\sum_k m^\ast(E_k\setminus F_k)\leqq\epsilon.$

Maybe what I did so far is correct, but this is not sufficient yet : I have to check

(i) $F$ is closed about relative topology from $E$.

(ii) $f|_F$ is continuous.

For (i), each $F_k$ is closed in $E_k$ but I don't know why $F=\cup_k F_k$ is closed in $E$. $F$ has to be written as $F=E\cap C$, where $C$ in closed in $\mathbb R$. I haven't found such $C$.

For (ii), each $f|_{F_k}$ is continuous but I don't think this guarantees the continuity of $f|_F$. I think that "each $f|_{A_k}$ is continuous $\Rightarrow$ $f|_{\cup_{k=1}^\infty}A_k$ is continuous" doesn't generally hold. (Maybe, I have to show $x_j\to x$ $\Rightarrow$ $f|_F(x_j)\to f|_F(x)$, but I don't know how.)

**Postscript**

Hint says $E_k:=E\cap[-k,k]$ but perhaps $E_k$ has to be defined s.t. $\{E_k\}$ is disjoint : e.g., $E_k=E\cap(k,k+1]$ or, $E_1=E\cap[-1,1]$, $E_k=E\cap([-k,k]\setminus[1-k,k-1])$ for $k\geqq 2.$

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I see your postscript. I think defining $E_k=E\cap[k,k+1]$ is a much better idea, personally.

---

It is important to note that, with no loss of generality, $F_{n+1}\cap[-n,n]=F_n$ can be enforced for all $n\ge1$. This ensures $F$ is the colimit of $F_1\hookrightarrow F_2\hookrightarrow\cdots$ which is what we need for $f$ to be continuous, and also for $F$ to be closed. If you aren't comfortable with that language, ignore it!

$F$ is closed because $F\cap[-n,n]$ is a finite union of $F_1,F_2,\cdots,F_n$ which is closed, for every $n$. It follows $F\cap K$ is closed for every compact subset $K$ of $\Bbb R$ hence $F$ is closed, as $\Bbb R$ is compactly generated.

That's just one way to see it though. We can prove it more directly - suppose $(x_i)_{i\ge1}$ is a sequence of elements of $K$ converging to some $x\in\Bbb R$. If $n=\lceil x\rceil+1$, I know there is some $N$ that $i\ge N$ implies $x_i\in[-n,n]$, hence $x_i\in F_n$ for all $i\ge N$. Considering the sequence $y_j:=x_{j+N}$, we know $(y_j)_{j\ge1}$ is a sequence of elements of $F_n$ converging to $x$. Because this set is closed, I know $x\in F_n\subseteq F$. Thus, $x\in F$ - by the sequential criterion for closure of a set in a metric space, it follows $F$ is closed.

Why is $f$ continuous on $F$? Fix an $x\in F$ and $U$ an open neighbourhood of $f(x)$. I know $x\in F_n$ for some $n$, by definition of union. We may take $n>\lceil x\rceil+1$. Now, continuity of $f$ on $F_n$ implies there is some $1>\delta>0$ that $|y-x|<\delta$ and $y\in F_n$ implies $f(y)\in U$. If $y\in F$ and $|y-x|<\delta<1$, we know $y\in[-n,n]$ hence $y\in F_n$ holds, so this condition extends to: $y\in F$ and $|y-x|<\delta$ implies $f(y)\in U$. Since $U$ is arbitrary, we have $f$ continuous at $x$. Since $x$ is arbitrary, $f$ is continuous over all of $F$.

Comment: I understand there is $N$ s.t. $i\geqq N \Rightarrow x_i\in[-n,n]$, but why does this imply $x_i\in\cup_{k=1}^n F_k$ for $i\geqq N$ ?

Comment: @daㅤ We know two things. $x_i\in[-n,n]$ and $x_i\in F$. So, $x_i\in F_k$ for some $k$, $x_i\in F_k\cap[-n,n]$. By my simplifying assumption (which is possible to achieve wlog and is necessary for bits of the proof to work) I know $F_k\cap[-n,n]\subseteq F_n$ for any $k$. So $x_i\in F_n$ for all $i\ge N$ (I know I wrote ‘union’ in the post, that was before I realise the simplifying assumption is quite important: I’ll edit in that change now)

Comment: I put the simplifying assumptions after that paragraph where I really should have written it in before, to emphasise - that’s fixed now

Comment: My $F_n$ only satisfies $m^\ast(F_n)<\infty$ and $F_n\subset_{\rm{closed}} E_n$. I cannot see why we can enforce $F_{n+1}\cap[-n,n]=F_n$.

Comment: @daㅤYou can pick the $F_n$ in this way. Do so by induction, say we have chosen the $F_n$ in this way up to step $N$. In picking $F_{N+1}$, I can notice that $E_{N+1}\setminus\mathrm{int}F_n$ is a measure space on which $f$ is measurable, so by the finite Lusin theorem there is a relatively closed $K$ on which $f$ is continuous and $E_{N+1}\setminus K$ has small measure. $K$ is going to be relatively closed in $E_{N+1}$ too, and $F_{N+1}:=K\cup F_N$ is relatively closed in $E_{N+1}$, satisfies that $f$ is continuous on it, and $E_{N+1}\setminus F_{N+1}$ can be made to have small measure

Comment: Does such $F_N$ satisfiy $F_{N+1}\cap[-N,N]=F_N$? I have $F_{N+1}\cap[-N,N]=(K\cup F_N)\cap[-N,N]=(K\cap[-N,N])\cup(F_N\cap[-N,N])$, but does this become $F_N$ ?

Comment: @da Sure, $K\cap[-N,N]$ could be nonempty. But that would mean $A:=F_N\cup(K\cap[-N,N])$ is a relatively closed subset of $E_N$, with the complement having small measure, and $f$ shall be continuous on it. So we may as well have taken $F_N=A$ in the first place. That is, we can take the $F_i$ to be maximal relatively closed subsets in this regard. So we can arrange it to be the case that $K\cap[-N,N]$ is empty.